# How to solve "Invalid Printer Specified" error in c# winforms?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports-2010

I am sure this is pretty much frequently asked question, but I can't find any answer suitable for me.  Please consider below scenario.

**Scenario**
I have developed a **C# Winform** application with **SAP Crystal Report** for **VS2010** for a Restaurant. After completing an Order, the Invoice need to printed directly to the printer. Below is the code I am using.

```
oMainOrder.SetDataSource(oDSOrderReport);

if (_sPrintOrShow.ToLower() == "print")
{
   oMainOrder.PrintOptions.PrinterName = printDialog.PrinterSettings.PrinterName;
   //Above line provides the name of the default printer, which is also my target printer

   oMainOrder.PrintToPrinter(1, false, 0, 0);
}

else
{
   frmShowReport reportViewerForm = new frmShowReport(oDSOrderReport);
   reportViewerForm.ShowDialog();
}
```

**_sPrintOrShow** is a variable which determines whether the invoice will be sent directly to the printer or will be loaded in a report viewer form. When **_sPrintOrShow** is set to **print**, it is likely that the invoice will be sent to the printer. On my end and my USB printer, this works fine. But when I provide this same solution to my client, he gets the exception "**Invalid Printer Specified**". The more frustrating thing is, if the invoice is loaded in the report viewer form, then from there I can print the invoice to the same printer without any problem. I have absolutely no idea, why is this happening? Can any of you help me in this as you have done previously? Thanks.

Comment: It certainly looks right to me.  Can you try outputting the printer name to the screen or a log file, to be sure that it's actually returning good data?

Comment: In addition to @Bobson recommendation, once you have the printer name try simply printing to it with a notepad file. Does this work?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just after some quick searching I found an Example of your code used identically and someone posted that it does not work as expected via SAP forums and provided a line to this [Matt Ruma](http://www.mattruma.com/?p=258).  Worth a Shot not sure if it works just trying to help out.

Comment: The post of @MattRuma certainly helps !! Thanks.

Comment: The link is no longer valid. If you still have the content, please paste it in the answer.